# Код для вычисления факториалов (IndexError: list index out of range)

Tags: python, index

Создал код для вычисления факториалов. Всё работает, но вылетает ошибка IndexError: list index out of range. Как можно исправить?

```
ch = int(input('Введите число '))
l = list(range(1, ch + 1))
print(l)
p = 1
if ch >= 0:
    if ch < 2:
        print(1)
    else:
        while p != ch + 1:
            s = l[0] * l[1]
            del l[0]
            l[0] = s
            p = p + 1
            print(l[0])
```

Comment: На последней итерации какая длина списка?  А вообще -  зачем вам такой код? Если вы на бумаге считаете факториал, разве занимаетесь удалением чисел и т.п.?

Answer (score 0):

Измените строчку `while p != ch + 1:` на `while p != ch + 1 and len(l) != 1:`

Comment: Лучше факториал искать через рекурсивную функцию, но вы просили исправить ваш код, что собственно я и сделал.

Comment: факториал лучше искать через ``math.factorial()`` ;)

Comment: Рекурсия в питоне хороша только для учебных целей. Так то лучше циклом делать.